# Is natural selection still at work in humans in the 21st century?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, human-evolution

There has been some disussion on this site about some aspects (e.g. evolution of [eye sight](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17678/bad-eyesight-and-evolution), or [height](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/457/height-and-natural-selection-in-humans), or the [effect of medicine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17306/is-there-a-possibility-that-medicine-will-affect-the-efficiency-of-natural-selec), or evolution [the past $\sim10000$ years](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20291/human-evolution-in-modern-times)). My question is really more general regarding evolution and more specific regarding the current age. I'm looking for answer with references to original research if possible.

Comment: @Remi.b Thanks for finding this. The question is indeed similar, but the answers are not what I'm looking for, as they consider recent evolution (in the past 10000 yrs). I'm wondering about the today. Our cultur today is very different from that 10000 years ago and this might strongly effect natural selection.

Comment: You really cannot view evolution today.. But it is definitely happening..because humans are no more segregated populations but as a famous TV personality said a global community. But two hundred years from now when we have put colonies on Mars and then a thousand years from then you can expect Martian populations to carry traits that are a bit different from Earth humans.... I think you get my point.... That one of things required for viewing evolution is a niche population which has no exterior generic pressure...and lots of time....these are just my thoughts based on what i know till now...

Comment: Selection is still occurring because there are many genetic effects on reproductive output - some die before being able to reproduce, there are effects on fertility, behavioural traits (including those making one more or less prone to wanting children)... it is a duplicate as that is covered in the linked question which also focuses on very modern humans

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Selection is most certainly occurring in *all populations* of humans. The modern cultural and social advances have *altered* the adaptive landscape, not flattened it. In some genes, net selection may even be stronger now. We also have continued evolution of the meta population, along with selection, by drift and mutation, as well as migration among populations leading to further evolution within sub populations.