# How to teach my self Biology and Chemistry?

Tags: biochemistry

Long story short I'm a American dreamer (a immigrant brought to the USA as a child but is illegal) and recently returned to my home country and not knowing the language here have had a hard time at school I am now 22 and think I can finally get somewhere I just need to teach my self Biology and Chemistry (Childhood dream was to be a biologist of some sorts) but I don't know where to start.

Can anyone recommend and books how how I should start my studying? I need to learn this stuff to be able to get into a university here. I wan't to start from the start and work my way up to University level.

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance

Edit: TLDR: Basically I'm asking how I can home school my self to learn Biology and Chemistry to be able to get into a University and learn Biology and Chemistry on a University degree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Books for beginners](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/books-for-beginners). There are also other posts that are more specific (such as [Very introductory online source of information in evolutionary biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34154/very-introductory-online-source-of-information-in-evolutionary-biology) e.g.) that can be of interest to you.

Comment: I am sorry you've been evicted from the US to a country you know little about and don't speak the local language. As unfair as this situation sounds to me, I would like to reassure by saying that you will quickly learn this new language and will be able to attend classes like anyone else. Hopefully, this country has a decent education system and you will be able to pursue your education as you please.

Comment: For chemistry, please see on [chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The stated clearly series is a good introduction to evolutionary concepts,  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_cznB5YZZmvAmeq7Y3EriQ. Personally I like Richard Dawkins books like the selfish gene and the extended phenotype, they are also fairly easy to come by.